# shell script to copy log files in /tmp directories for specific time interval

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to write a shell script to copy the log files generating with in 1 hour to /tmp directory. This script I would like to schedule in cron so that this job can be run at every hour and copy the new generated log file into /tmp.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You put a file as an argument, it shows you logs that are happening...
you can change the script to redirect from stdout to a file...

```
#!/bin/bash

GAP=10     #How long to wait
LOGFILE=$1 #File to log to

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]
then
    echo "USAGE: ./watch-log.sh <file with absolute path>"
    exit 1
fi


#Get current long of the file
len=`wc -l $LOGFILE | awk '{ print $1 }'`
echo "Current size is $len lines."

while :
do
    if [ -N $LOGFILE ] 
    then
        echo "`date`: New Entries in $LOGFILE: "
        newlen=`wc -l $LOGFILE | awk ' { print $1 }'`
        newlines=`expr $newlen - $len`
        tail -$newlines $LOGFILE
        len=$newlen
    fi
    sleep $GAP
done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using find command will be able to achieve the above, Assuming /tmp is not in the search path
and log files are with .log extension

```
find $PATH_TO_SEARCH -type f -name "*.log" -cmin -60 -exec cp {} /tmp \;
# Above single command can be configured as cron job.
```